# RecyclerView does not showing all items when its in a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

I Have 2 `RecyclerViews` in a `LinearLayout` inside a `ScrollView` :

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/few_value">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.foodjoo.fjco.customViews.BYekanFontText
            android:id="@+id/market_category"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:padding="@dimen/normal_plus_value"
            android:text=" لبنیات > مارکت پیکی علی  "
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
            android:textColor="@color/light_black2" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/market_cat_recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <com.foodjoo.fjco.customViews.BYekanFontText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:padding="@dimen/normal_plus_value"
            android:text="ساعات کار"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
            android:textColor="@color/light_black2" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/market_hours_recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

both recyclers have `nestedScrollEnabled` flase .

the problem is here : 
when the layout rendered, first recyclerView will fill and the second recyclerView in bottom of screen will not showing all items because of first one  height !! 
But it should scroll , because both of them are in scrollView !!

so Whats the Problem ?

Comment: have you tried removing the scrollview?

Comment: Try to set height of second recycler view to wrap_content

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley i need the scrollView to scroll the page ,it cant be removed

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava still not working :(

Comment: Can you post your activity as well !

Comment: @Mehdibmp you will have to give manual height to both recycleViews because they both are in a scrollview so it won't work if you give wrap_content or match_parent.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use `NestedScrollView`instead of `ScrollView`

and add `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` to your `RecyclerView`

Comment: nice solution ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try giving manual `height` to both **recycleViews** because they both are in a `scrollview` so it won't work if you give `wrap_content` or `match_parent`.

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.foodjoo.fjco.customViews.BYekanFontText
        android:id="@+id/market_category"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:padding="@dimen/normal_plus_value"
        android:text=" لبنیات > مارکت پیکی علی  "
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
        android:textColor="@color/light_black2" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/market_cat_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp" />

    <com.foodjoo.fjco.customViews.BYekanFontText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:padding="@dimen/normal_plus_value"
        android:text="ساعات کار"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
        android:textColor="@color/light_black2" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/market_hours_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```